# How to import function from a sub-file within a folder (without having to refer to the name of the sub-file)

Tags: python, python-import

I have written a bunch of functions stored in different python files over the past years that I would like to dump into a folder and just use 'import folder' to call the functions from those python files.

So far, all the solutions I have read needs to either:

```py
    from folder.pyfilename import func1 
    func1()
```

or

```py
    from folder import *
    pyfilename.func1()
```

Does anyone know if it's possible to do something like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a file `folder/__init__.py` and have it do the subfolder imports.

`__init__.py`

```
from .prog1 import foo, bar
from .prog2 import baz

__all__ = ["foo", "bar", "baz"]
```

`__all__` lists the variables that are imported by `from foo import *` so its not really all of the names, but it is all of the names the implementer thinks you should care about.

Now you can write programs that do

```
from folder import *

foo()
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! This is by far the closet to what I wanted!

Answer (score 1):

Your question doesn't make too much sense to be honest, however you could do something like this:

```py
    import folder.program as prog
    from folder import program2 as prog2
    prog.function()
    prog2.function()
```

In case you don't know, the `as` keyword is used to create an alias.

As far as I'm aware, you can't do what you want. You have to tell python which file the function is in.

I'm guessing you want to import the whole folder because it would take a while to add all the imports? I think you would just have to copy all the functions you want into one single file - or `import` each file/function as you already have done.

Comment: Yeah I had too much python files and each had a bunch of functions, so I was thinking of skipping the step of calling the python file names, but I guess it's not quite possible. Thanks for letting me know!

Comment: @XianLi No problem!